# gulp: Module parse failed

Tags: json, npm, gulp, webpack, laravel-elixir

I'm working with Laravel 5.3.

Errors I get after installing node-uuid.

> { [Error: ./~/diffie-hellman/lib/primes.json
>   Module parse failed: /var/www/html/filecloudprod/node_modules/diffie-hellman/lib/primes.json Unexpected token (2:11)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

My package.json file. **Note json-loader**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-browsersync-official": "^1.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "dropzone": "^4.3.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.0",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4"
  }
}
```

Then tried to merge webpack config like this in gulpfile.
I tried 2 different approaches, see TRY1 and TRY2, certainly not at the same time, just posted both approaches.

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

// TRY 1
elixir.webpack.mergeConfig({
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json'
        }]
    }
});

// TRY 2 
elixir.ready(() => {
    elixir.config.js.webpack = {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json'
        }]
    }
});

elixir(function (mix) {

    mix.sass('app.scss');

    mix.webpack('app.js');

    mix.browserSync({
        proxy: 'filecloud.dev'
    });    

    mix.version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
});
```

But I still get the error.

**Full error**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use npm modules which requires the **json-loader**, this is the solution.

Add following to package.json file.

> "json-loader": "^0.5.4"

Create webpack.config.js with the following code:

```
Elixir.webpack.mergeConfig({

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json'
        }]
    }
});
```

Now you can require packages in your bootstrap.js file which require the json-loader.

**Additional Notes**

When you look to the index.js file where the webpack method of elixir is defined, you see that the json loader is missing inside the loaders array.

```
module: {
    loaders: [{ test: /\.js$/, loader: 'buble', exclude: /node_modules/ }]
},
```